# My datagridview export to Excel has incomplete data

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export

I have managed to import my data from a text file into a datagridview,
and the datagridview data look exactly the same as my text file.
But, when I export the datagridview to Excel, some of the row information is missing.

Here is my code to get the info from my text file into the datagridview.

```
public void AIO1Res()
{
    OpenFileDialog DialogA1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogA1.Filter = "AIO File (*.txt) | *.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (DialogA1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string FileName = DialogA1.FileName;
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);
        if (lines.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var cellValues in lines.Skip(0))
            {
                var cellArray = cellValues.ToString()
                    .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                if (cellArray.Length == DGAIO1.Columns.Count)
                    DGAIO1.Rows.Add(cellArray).ToString();
            }
        }
```

Here is my code to then export it to Excel.

```
newSheet.Name = "Test Results";                  
newSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";

for (int i = 0; i < DGAIO1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < DGAIO1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        newSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = DGAIO1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

datagridview:
[image: datagridview]

Excel Export:
[image: Excel Export]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What are the characters between **01** and **Pass** in the third line ? Are there any **tab** ?

Comment: I copied the text into a word doc to see the format, and they appear to be just spaces, with a carriage return at the end.